# How can I fade a UIView in while moving it up?

Tags: objective-c

I have a UIView and I want to give it an effect that causes it to start with an alpha of 0 and then while moving up 50 pixels animated it also changes to an alpha of 1. How can this be done in Objective-C?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for `UIView` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    //here change position and alpha 
    CGRect newFrame = view.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += 50;
    view.frame = newFrame;
    view.alpha = 1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    //called when animation did finish. do what you want
}];
```

Comment: Don't animate the alpha to both 0 and 1 inside the animation. It should be at 0 before the animation. Just set it to 1 in the animation.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, i mean set alpha to 0 before start animation =)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html

Everything about animations.
It's all right there.

```
//something similar to what you want:

- (IBAction)showHideView:(id)sender
{
    // Fade out the view right away
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
        delay: 0.0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
             thirdView.alpha = 0.0;
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){
            // Wait one second and then fade in the view
            [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 delay: 1.0
                 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                    thirdView.alpha = 1.0;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
        }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
UIView *box = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, 100, 50)];
box.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
box.alpha = 0.0f;
[self.view addSubview:box];


[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                 animations:^{
                     box.alpha = 1.0f;
                     CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y - 100, 100, 50);
                     [box setFrame:frame];
                 }];
```